# PHP - making a script to show entered data

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and i need to know how to display entered data on a page. I will clarify. There is a text box on a page and when the user types something in it and clicks submit, a blank page will come up that says: You entered [ENTERED DATA HERE]. i want to do this so that i put a code in the text box, and it will automatically generate the correct iframe.

`<iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://jb-radio.com/movies/play.php?mu=[ENTERED DATA HERE]" frameborder="0" height="360" scrolling="no" width="640"></iframe>`

Please help on this script (i think it is done with PHP) i think this should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in client-side Javascript with no PHP involved:

```
 <iframe id="the_iframe" style="display:none;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="" frameborder="0" height="360" scrolling="no" width="640"></iframe>

 <input id="the_input" type="text" />
 <input id="the_button" type="button" value="Click me to change the iframe" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('the_button').onclick = function() {
     var theUrl = 'http://jb-radio.com/movies/play.php?mu=';
     theUrl = theUrl + document.getElementById('the_input').value;
     var theIframe = document.getElementById('the_iframe');
     theIframe.style.display = 'block';
     theIframe.src = theUrl;
   };
 </script>
```

[Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/93yPT/)

Comment: looks good! is there any way that instead of creating the iframe, it will output the iframe CODE?

Comment: Yep, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93yPT/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Creating and working with forms is a fairly basic topic. Use Google to look up some intro php lessons. I used tizag when I started. Your solution will involve the use of the $_POST or $_GET superglobal (depending on the form method).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you get the parameter value from a url

```
url = "http://www.example.com/test.php?example_id=123"

$id_1 = $_GET['example_id'];  //equals 123 from the URL parameter
```

To set your iframe url you will need to include that $id

```
<iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="http://jb-radio.com/movies/play.php?mu=<?php $id ?>" frameborder="0" height="360" scrolling="no" width="640"></iframe>
```

This is assuming your page is using a .php extension and not .html.  If you want to use a .html page your server needs to be able to parse the .php.